# invalid column error while executing query in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm writing a stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_wellbehavior]
(
    @tuwi nvarchar(50),
    @country varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @query as nvarchar(1800)
    declare @SchemaName as varchar(100)
    declare @well_name as nvarchar(100)
    declare @number as INT

    set @number = cast(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @tuwi) as varchar)
    set @SchemaName = case @country
        when 'US' Then  'wellbehaviour_US'
        when 'Canada' Then  'wellbehaviour_Canda'
        when 'Australia' Then  'wellbehaviour_Australia'
        when 'Japan' Then 'wellbehaviour_Japan'
        when 'China' Then 'wellbehaviour_China'    
    END
    
    set @well_name = (select well_name from well.well_mapping where index_id = @tuwi)
    set @query = 'SELECT [date], [asset], [index_id], [well_name], [open], [gas], [oil], [water], [whp],    [wht], [bhp], 
    [bht], [cluster], [flag], [display_cluster] FROM datascience.'+@SchemaName+ ' where well_view_id ='+@tuwi
    
    Execute sp_executesql @query
END
```

Stored procedure is creation is successful without any errors. But when I try to execute the stored procedure

with below statements

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @tuwi nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @country varchar(50)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_wellbehavior]
@tuwi = 'Z303400', @country ='Japan'

GO
```

It is showing below error:

[image]

Need a help to resolve this error in SQL-Server

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and then post the error as TEXT (not as IMAGE, because it only contains text)

Comment: Error msg: Invalid column name 'Z303400'

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: you need to add quotes around '+@tuwi. or even better use proper parametrized dynamic sql

Comment: Print your dynamic SQL to debug it. A d correct your title which currently says MySQL

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You need to deal with that pronto.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: `Z303400` will not be a character literal in the dynamic SQL. Because it's currently unquoted SQL Server is treating it as a column name and isn't able to resolve it to a database column referenced anywhere in the statement. Have you tried something like `QUOTENAME(@tuwi, '''')` it to produce `'Z303400'` in the dynamic SQL?

Comment: I have tried using the QUOTENAME also still it is showing the same error

Comment: Are you sure you're applying `QUOTENAME(@tuwi, '''')` in the right place? Ref: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OM-3URoz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `@tuwi` value is not being escaped properly. But you shouldn't be injecting it either way, instead pass it to `sp_executesql` as a proper parameter.

Furthermore:

- Dynamic query variables should be `nvarchar(max)`.
- Object and schema names should be `sysname`.
- Use `QUOTENAME` to correctly quote injected names.
- Always specify the length of a `varchar`.
- Exactly what the purpose of `@number` and `@well_name` is unclear as they aren't being used.
- Unclear what you are trying to do, but I'm guessing `PATINDEX` doesn't do what you think it does.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_wellbehavior]
    @tuwi nvarchar(50),
    @country varchar(50)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
  @query nvarchar(max),
  @TableName sysname;

SET @TableName = case @country
    when 'US' Then  'wellbehaviour_US'
    when 'Canada' Then  'wellbehaviour_Canda'
    when 'Australia' Then  'wellbehaviour_Australia'
    when 'Japan' Then 'wellbehaviour_Japan'
    when 'China' Then 'wellbehaviour_China'    
END;
    
SET @query = '
SELECT
  date, asset, index_id, well_name,
  open, gas, oil, water, whp,
  wht, bhp, bht, cluster, flag, display_cluster
FROM datascience.' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '
where well_view_id = @tuwi;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @query,
  N'@tuwi nvarchar(50)',
  @tuwi = @tuwi;
```